Is it possible for a razor page to return a 40X status?
I thought this may have been simple but i have read a number of threads and cant figure this out, leading me to think it might not be possible (but since i have a webforms background i was able to do this but not in MVC)
I have a razor page, on this page i want to return a 40X status code. I dont want to create a Controller for this i just want it to return a 40X status code where X could be a valid value. The code should reside on this View only. Is this possible?
I have tried
@{
return NotFound;
}
@{
return Response.XXXX
}
but either i get an error stating the NotFound is a void method or i just dont have access to any method to return a response with that status.
Is it possible, if so any examples?

You can't just return a status code from within the Razor markup itself. That’s not how it works. The response needs to be handled in the backend code, not in the view.

How exactly are you imaging this should work without a controller? If the page has been served to the client, what's returning the 40x and to whom?

I assume you are just using Razor Pages right? No Controllers? Are you using a Layout for your pages? This can be done in the view, if you are not using a layout.

@mxmissile thats correct. Theres no layout but i dont see any examples of how this is possible?

Assuming you are in fact using MVC, not Razor Pages, there is no way to do this without a controller.

Assuming you are using Razor Pages and not MVC and not using a layout page you can hack your view with:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return;
}

However it would better to to do this in your page's OnGet() method:
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return NotFound();
}

